# Windows automount and unmount USB drive

Tags: windows, automount

I have a Windows 2003 domain controller machine which I use to back up data nightly, weekly, and monthly using ntbackup. An external USB storage device is connected to it with 3x 500Gb drives. We have calculated that it can store a weeks worth of backups on a single 500Gb drive. Once the first drive is full, I would like the Windows machine or script to unmount the first drive and mount the next available drive automatically.

I've heard of ways to do this, but I could not find the source in my searches. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Happy New year!

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Microsoft's DevCon utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272), I use it to disconnect eSATA HDD's at the end of backup batch files so the users don't have to log in and 'safely remove' them before swapping drives.

It might be able to at least help you accomplish some of what you're doing. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used [SyncSE](http://www.2brightsparks.com/syncback/sbse-features.html) for this kind of purpose, and it's never let me down.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I would prefer to use a native Windows script or open source application before I venture into the proprietary applications.